# What is the point of using an empty column in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-component

I am unable to get this code to run so I am trying to just figure out what it does by looking at it. So, can someone please explain to me what is going on here? Where are there 2 columns but one is empty?

Also, am I correct in thinking that whatever route is triggered, the content will show up within column 2? The `Routes` component is just a `Switch` with a ton of `Routes`.

```
    <BrowserRouter>
      <NavigationBar />
      <Route exact path="/" component={LoginComponent} />
      <Container fluid="true">
        <Row>
          <Col xs={0} sm={0} md={0} lg={0} xl={1} />
          <Col xs={12} sm={7} md={8} lg={9} xl={8}>
            <Alert />
            <Route component={Routes} />
          </Col>
          <UserPanel />
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the point of using an empty column in React?

Apparently, they want some blank space on the screen when the screen size is extra large.

> Also, am I correct in thinking that whatever route is triggered, the content will show up within column 2

From your description of the code in `Routes`, that seems correct.

Comment: Okay thanks, I know it was a pretty dumb question. Since I can’t get the code to run I just had to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the empty col is used as a placeholder on xl screen.
You should read source code to understand what a component does, then you can understand and not guess the point.

As for your second question, The [react router docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/path-string-string) states that:

> Routes without a path always match.

So whatever Routes component renders - it will be rendered on any given route.